# Pinescript V5 Coding Issue with Syntax error ':=' and '='

Tags: syntax-error, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I keep getting Syntax error at input '=' with the below code

`var float[] y1 = array.new_float(16) for i = 0 to 15 y1[i] = ta.sma(array.get(xx, i), 16)`

And Syntax error at input ':=' with the below code as well. tried both things to fix it and still nothing works.

`var float[] y1 = array.new_float(16) for i = 0 to 15 y1[i] := ta.sma(array.get(xx, i), 16)`

Any possible solutions? Doing this in Pinescript V5

Comment: It is always helpful to read documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign values to an array that way.

You need to use the `array.set()` function.

```
array.set(id, index, value) → void
```